# problems use scatter for 2 array

Tags: c++, mpi

I want use scatter for arrays a,b in my program.but this have problem when i run.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int n,subarrsize,rank,p,nproc,j,i,sizearr=16;
int **A,**B,**C,**SA,**SB;


MPI::Init(argc, argv);
nproc = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

sizearr=atoi(argv[1]);
if(sizearr%nproc!=0)
{
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Abort(1);
}

subarrsize=sizearr/(int)nproc;
SA=alloc_2d_init(subarrsize,sizearr);
SB=alloc_2d_init(subarrsize,sizearr);

if(rank==0)
{
    A=alloc_2d_init(sizearr,sizearr);
    B=alloc_2d_init(sizearr,sizearr);
    C=alloc_2d_init(sizearr,sizearr);

    for (i = 0; i < sizearr; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < sizearr; ++j) {
            A[i][j]=rand()%100;
            B[i][j]=rand()%100;
        }
    }
    }
   MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatter(&(A[0][0]),subarrsize*sizearr,MPI_INT,&(SA[0]
     [0]),subarrsize*sizearr,MPI_INT,0);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatter(&(B[0][0]),subarrsize*sizearr,MPI_INT,&(SB[0]
     [0]),subarrsize*sizearr,MPI_INT,0);
    for(int p=0;p<nproc;++p)
{
    if(rank==p)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<"RANK: "<<rank<<"\n";
        cout<<"A:\n";
        for(i=0;i<subarrsize;++i)
            {
                for(j=0;j<sizearr;++j)
                        cout<<SA[i][j]<<"\t";
                cout<<"\n";
            }
                   cout<<"B:\n";
            for(i=0;i<subarrsize;++i)
            {
                    for(j=0;j<sizearr;++j)
                        cout<<SB[i][j]<<"\t";
                    cout<<"\n";
            }
    }
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Barrier();
}
   if(rank==0)
{
    free2d(&SA);
    free2d(&A);
}
MPI::Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

I found problems.scatter function get first argument that is pointers to arrays A,B and  i just define these pointers in process 0 so other process haven't got the pointers.
i changed my code:

```
int *Aptr,*Bptr;
if(rank==0)
{
  A=alloc_2d_init(sizearr,sizearr);
  B=alloc_2d_init(sizearr,sizearr);
  Aptr=&(A[0][0]);
  Bptr=&(B[0[0]);
  .
  .
}
 else
{
    Aptr=NULL;
    Bptr=NULL;
}
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatter(Aptr,subarrsize*sizearr,MPI_INT,&(SA[0]
    [0]),subarrsize*sizearr,MPI_INT,0);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatter(Bptr,subarrsize*sizearr,MPI_INT,&(SB[0]
    [0]),subarrsize*sizearr,MPI_INT,0);
```

Comment: What's the problem / error ?

Comment: i have this error:BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES,EXIT CODE: 139,CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES,YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES,APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)

Comment: That's not the real error. You're probably seeing a segmentation fault right? Do you have a core dump or anything you can take a look at?

Comment: i'm newbie in mpi,i install mpich2 on ubuntu 12.10.i dont know core dump.

Comment: Have you ever used a debugger (GDB)? This isn't an MPI thing. This is a general programming thing.

Comment: no,i haven't.i'm installed eclipse Kepler and Parallel Application Developer but i can't debug my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the (sub)arrays so that the data is in consecutive memory (e.g. if you `malloc` in a loop, the data layout is not a good fit for MPI).

can you please post your `alloc_2d_init()` function so we can have a look at advise from there ?